# what is the meaning for the orientation of pr2 arm in cartesion controller?

Tags: ros, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to use the keyboard control the pr2 simulator, but Ĩ can not get a clear idea about the mean setting of orientation.

```
cmd.pose.orientation.x=-0.00244781865415;
cmd.pose.orientation.y=-0.548220284495;
cmd.pose.orientation.z=0.00145617884538;
cmd.pose.orientation.w=0.836329126239;
```

That is in the demo source code.
How can  I set this value to make the gripper is vertical face the table so as to grasp the object on the table.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28570/what-is-the-meaning-for-the-orientation-of-pr2-arm-in-cartesion--controller?/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The orientation is represented as a quaternion. The related question/answer on this site can be found [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9981/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them?answer=14611#answer-container-14611).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0